# Suggestions for programming structure and storing of animatronic sequences

Tags: arduino

I'm working on some [animatronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animatronics) for an art installation which will use several stepper motors and some high-power LEDs. In the past, when I have done this sort of thing I have used a tethered computer to handle the logic and timing. For this project, I would like to try making it self-contained (for example, just the Arduino board). For Arduino hardware, I have an [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega) and could expand it with an [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) for more storage, if need be.

I'd really welcome any ideas or suggestions on how to approach this (and am not asking for code).

For the data, essentially I would be storing cues for each stepper and each LED. And of course I would need some kind of clock or timestamp to keep track of things.

A stepper cue would be something like:

- cue start time
- stepper ID
- stepper direction
- stepper speed
- number of steps

An LED cue would be something like:

- cue start time
- LED ID
- Start brightness
- End brightness
- duration

So what I am wondering about:

- ideas about a data format compact enough to store lots of cues
- any suggestions for a clock or timestamp. (A simple counter is the obvious choice.)

As for just how many cues/how much data, since I am just beginning this, I will work within whatever limits I bump up against.

Comment: The MIDI format is often (ab)used for this kind of non-music data. (theater lighting, etc) Maybe you could use it for your robot-ballet, too. MIDI is extremely lightweight wrt storage-size, and relatively easy to parse.

Comment: @wildplasser - interesting, thanks. I've seen MIDI ab/used for this too but that completely hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: It has al the core functionality built-in: timing, cueing / synchronisation, multiple voices / channels. (IIRC loops / repetitions were added later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for now I have decided to roll my own simple data format in order to keep the project moving. I was also concerned about storing cue data in a way that doesn't eat up RAM.

Since I am using an Ardunio Mega with 128 KB of Flash memory I want to use that before resorting to an SD card. With the excellent [Flash Library](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/flash/) accessing PROGMEM is very easy and I was able to rough out a test sketch in minutes.

For motor control I am using dedicated motor controller boards using serial comm. Each board controls two motors. For testing the maximum data size I needed to send was four values: *rate, slope, x target, y target* in order to make a move so that determines my data format for motors.  This will change when I add a timestamp and board ID values.

With the Flash lib, you can define a FLASH_TABLE, store it in PROGMEM and then access it using simple array bracket access. Testing with a couple of thousand entries shows no issues.

So it becomes a simple task of pulling data out and sending it to the standalone boards or using it internally.

// simple example:

```
#include <Flash.h>

FLASH_TABLE(int, command_table, 4 /* width of table */, 
    {111, 222, 333, 444},
    {1001, 900, 3210, -4567},
    {1002, 1000, 3210, -4567},
    {1003, 1100, 3210, -4567},
    {666, 777, 888, 999}
    );

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.print("Mem: "); Serial.println(availableMemory());

    // Determine the size of the array
    Serial.print("Rows: "); Serial.println(command_table.rows());
    Serial.print("Cols: "); Serial.println(command_table.cols());
    Serial.print("RAM: "); Serial.println(sizeof(command_table));

     Serial.print(command_table[8][0]);
     Serial.print("s");
     Serial.print(command_table[8][1]);
     Serial.print("r");
     Serial.print(command_table[8][2]);
     Serial.print("x");
     Serial.print(command_table[8][3]);
     Serial.print("y");
     Serial.println("gi");  
}

void loop() {


}

int availableMemory() 
{
  int size = 1024;
  byte *buf;
  while ((buf = (byte *) malloc(--size)) == NULL);
  free(buf);
  return size;
}
```